# Ascend p6 stuck after flashing twrp recovery

Tags: huawei-ascend-ii

I've rooted my Ascend P6 and installed a CWM recovery. I then wanted to flash a TWRP recovery. When I rebooted the phone was stuck on the boot logo. I tried to push boot and recovery Images extracted from the stock firmware but ADB says that remote partition don't exist. I think I've destroyed phone file system.

It is stuck at boot logo, and no boot/recovery partitions are recognised by adb.

How can fix my phone so that it boots and is usable again?

Comment: If we're to help you we will need to know a lot more details. What exactly did you do, what have you tried (if anything)? You should probably also rephrase so that you actually ask a question, although I assume that it's regarding getting your device booting again.

Comment: @bmdixon thank you sir, sorry, first time in here. I've rooted a P6 then I've installed a cwm recovery, then I wanted to flash a twrp recovery. When I've rebooted I had phone stucked on boot logo, I tried to push boot and recovery Images extracted from stock firmware but ADB says that remote partition don't exist. I think I've destroyed phone file system.

Comment: Can you boot into Recovery (ignoring ADB altogether)?

Comment: No recovery, no fastboot. If I push power/vol+ or power/vol- is the same. Bootlogo and no more.

Comment: Without recovery or fastboot or an equivalent of 'download mode' you may need to go to a repair shop or someone with a JTag or similar hardware.